# Why isn't ether value not showing in etherscan transaction?

Tags: solidity, transactions, etherscan, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I called a `fund` function and sent 0.55 ether to this contract. Now called `withdraw` function and all the ethers in the contract came back to my metamask account. But in the screenshot below you can see the withdraw function, in the value section it is showing 0. It should show 0.55.
[image]
CAN SOMEONE TELL ME WHY?

Comment: Can you please share contract address if verified, Or contract code.

Comment: @AbhijeetGawai 0xB501EfBDAF10Db01e3861ffbEd1a2799BF43a3B6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Withdraw()` actually 0.55 eth is sent to your wallet. You can click on transaction or click [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xffaf7475dff4f413310d6cf57439303ae04f416625240a5d228802caa79ef351) to see it.

**But why in this screenshot it is not shown? Lets understand step by step.**

*First Lets Understand why while calling `fund()` 0.55 eth is shown*

`fund()` is a payable function. So, When you called `fund()`, you sent `msg.value` parameter here as `0.55e18`. That why it is showing 0.55 eth as parameter in screenshot. And thus 0.55 eth is transferred to smart contract. Remember in this screenshot, only `msg.value` parameter is shown.

This `msg.value` parameter referes to how much ether is sent by user. Below call will make it clear to you.

`FundMe.fund({"from":account,"value":Wei(0.55e18)})` , This is call you have made. Here `"value"` is `msg.value` which is 0.55 eth

*Now Lets Understand why 0.55 eth not shown in `withdraw()`*

Here `withdraw()` is also payable function which is not needed.

Here `Fund.wihtdraw({"from":account})` this is your call. Here you havent passed any `msg.value` because you are not sending any ether to smart contract from your account. That why it shows 0 eth.

Though, Smart Contract have sent 0.55 eth to your wallet. Your call still has `msg.value` parameter as 0.

Remember, The values in screenshot is just `msg.value` parameter. It only means how much ether is transferred from your wallet to smart contract.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you have any doubt regarding please ask, i will provide more information.

Comment: Thank you for solving my doubt! Also so the withdraw function will still work if I remove `payable` from it?

Comment: Yes, It will work. Because you are not passing ```msg.value``` parameter while calling withdraw function.